# How to add image upload option in product custom options magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, magento-product-attributes

I would like to show custom options all values with their image icon for that I need to add the image with each custom option value. Please do not suggest any paid extension or module.

[image: Configurable product Custom Option]

Comment: Did you find a solution?